# How to use Web API with WS-Federation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ws-federation

I already have configured Federation service. I have to use Web API with WS-Federation service. As Federation services use cookies to store security tokens and there is no support of Cookies in Web API. Now, how to use Web API with WS-Federation?

Answer (score 0):

This link discussion will help you:
[Invoking webapi throws No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893657/invoking-webapi-throws-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r/40901972?noredirect=1#comment69187340_40901972)

It states that WebApi uses host's sign-in protocol.