# Invoking webapi throws No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I'm trying to follow an Azure sample to integrate Azure AD into my MVC 4.6 web app via WSFederation provided here 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

This sample works as expected. However, when I add a WebApi controller in the same MVC project and decorate with [Authorize] it errors out. I have an ajax request for GET method in this newly added WebApi controller.

Error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/85c96496-fbc6-4bf3-bfcc-fb51ca874527/wsfe…UIWNgv-EANzWADAQPCOqF--3c7KGt6G21ucvLkce_wMcwVguKz62ioyGPxQg&wa=wsignin1.0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:4279' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After you add the `Authorize` tag for the web API, you need to sign-in the web app before you call the Ajax to request this web API. Then the Ajax request will send the cookies automatically for the authentication and it would return the correct result.

If you call the Ajax request to the web API before you sign-in, since the web API is protected and the web app is integrating with Azure AD, the request would redirect to the login page of Azure AD which is not allowed cross domain request. That's the root reason for this issue.

Comment: Can't the protected webapi controller automatically redirect the user to login screen as other (protected) MVC controller does?

Comment: It already redirect the request to the login page of Azure AD(as the link the error message mentioned), however since you were using the Ajax so that  it is not possible to enable users login-in.  You can request the web API in browser directly, it should redirect users to the login page.

Comment: So how should i handle my scenario? Users of my web app can invoke WebApi via ajax or server side MVC controller action in any order. I can't force them to use MVC controller first. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: In this scenario, you need to prompt users login before then can call the web API using the Ajax. For example, you can hide the button before users sign-in.

Comment: Got it! Also, this example uses cookie storage for WS-Fed tokens. Is it recommended or there are other suggested options? Can I pass tokens in headers for MVC and WebApi both? If yes, can you please point me to some demos/documentations? Thanks again!

Comment: The MVC application is user-oriented, it is recommend use the cookie authentication instead of token so that the users can visit the page successfully in the web browser. And to use the token protected web API using Azure AD, you can refer the link [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect).  And since the orignal issue was resolved, I suggest that you reopen a new thread if you have any other issues.