# WsFederation without cookies in Asp.Net MVC 4.6 app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I'm trying to follow an Azure sample to integrate Azure AD into my MVC 4.6 web app via WSFederation provided here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

This sample uses cookies to store authentication token. After reading few articles, I'm bit confused with the choice of cookies to store authentication token generated by WS-Federation. Are there recommended alternatives?

Also, this web app would host webapi controllers too as part of same project.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The is some misunderstanding about the store the token using cookies.

When the app is redirected to Azure AD and the users enter the correct username and passwords, the app will verify the token from Azure AD and sign-in the web app.

Then the cookies authentication middle ware would append the cookies based on the claims of sign-in user for the users visit the page without login-in again.

And based on the [preview threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893657/invoking-webapi-throws-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-r), it seems that you want to using the token to protect the MVC application and web API. As I metioned that the MVC web page is user-oriented, cookie authentication is recommend.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. So if my MVC web app in-turn invokes WebApi, does my current choice of WS-Fed and cookie middleware still valid and recommended?

Comment: Yes, if the MVC web application and web API is in the same project and the web API is only exposed to the MVC web application. The cookie authentication is recommend. And if you also want to exposed the web API to other applications, you may consider using the token. And you can refer [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) about using the token middle ware to protect the web API.

Comment: In the provided sample, following code is used to retrieve the token

Comment: In the provided sample, following code is used to retrieve the token `
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(todoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
`. However, I'm using WS-Fed with Owin in my MVC project. How can I retrieve authentication token and pass it to Service call ? Thanks!